Запретить каким либо образом кэшировать изображения
Как можно выполнить так, что браузер не станет каким либо способом кэшировать изображения.
Имена которых
1-img-2.webp
2-img-5.webp
img-6.webp

и так далее, общее это img- и расширение .webp
Когда меняется параметр на странице Last-Modified, браузеры по новой подгружают, обновляют те же url изображений?

Что бы обновить кэш браузера, нужно в Chrome нажать Ctrl + R или Ctrl + F5, либо открыть панель разработки А12 и нажать правой кнопкой на значке перезагрузки в панели браузера, откроется подменю в котором будет - "Очистка кэша и жёсткая перезагрузка". А htaccess лишь может кэшировать на стороне сервера и браузер никак в этом не участвует. По сути каждому человеку в своём браузере нужно отключить кэширование страниц в настройках, а по умолчанию они стоят.

Если хотите, что бы браузер сразу изменил изображение у всех пользователей, нужно название нового изображения изменить. Иначе он думает, что это то же самое изображение.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B

Чтобы всегда получать новое изображение, в конце ссылки на картинку можно отправлять параметр текущий unix timestamp на клиенте, в таком случае изображение будет всегда загружаться по новой и кэширование на сервере трогать не нужно будет

Cache-Control: no-store

Так можно запретить кэширование. Также можно каждый раз при загрузке изображений добавлять в конце случайное число или timestamp.
